# Rails model custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an attribute (`:book`) in my database that I'd like to restrict to three different values >>> `:classic`, `:modern`, `:historic`

I want to create a custom validation, so that when it is created or updated, a user can't type in googly-moogly

```
book: classic
      modern
      historic
```

Answer (score 4):

In whatever model has the book attribute:

```
VALID_BOOKS = [:classic, :modern, :historic]

validate :has_valid_book

def has_valid_book
  return if VALID_BOOKS.include? book.to_sym
  errors.add :book, 'must be a valid book'
end
```

**Edit**

Thanks to MrYoshiji for pointing out this particular case can be simplified to

```
VALID_BOOKS = [:classic, :modern, :historic]

validates :book, inclusion: { in: VALID_BOOKS.map(&:to_s) }
```

I'll leave the more verbose example above in case your validations become more complex in the future (as often happens) and an actual method is required to solve the problem.

Comment: it can be simplified to a simple `validates :book, inclusion: { in: VALID_BOOKS.map(&:to_s) }`

Answer (score 0):

***Update from @travis***

**This would work only for a single value**:

You can also use Active Record Validations `acceptance` which receive an `:accept`option that determines the value that will be considered acceptance.

For example:

```
class library < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :book, acceptance: { accept: 'some value' }
end
```

*** end of update***

Check out the Rails Guide on [Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Following the answer of @Travis and the comment of @MrYoshiji, You can also assign the values you accept to a constant `VALID_BOOKS = [:classic, :modern, :historic]`

Then set up your callback as such:

```
validates :book, inclusion: { in: VALID_BOOKS.map(&:to_s) }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the `acceptance` case wouldn't work here.  It's used for a single possible correct value (hence the TOS example in the docs).

Comment: hmmm... Right, that is only for a single value. Thanks for letting me know.